# Rotation around 3d object on touch using min3d/Rajawali framework (android)

Tags: android, rotation, touch, rajawali

I am working on an algorithm for rotating the camera around a 3D object using the Min3d/Rajawali framework.

With my implementation, the rotation around axis X is not working properly. I think the method `setLookAt()` is not working properly.

**The problem:**

When I rotate the sphere vertically, I can't fully see it. For example, turning the planet Earth, I can not fully see the Antarctic, because the algorithm resets the camera down.

Is it possible to realize the camera rotation around an object without using the method "setLookAt"?

I have tried different solutions, but have not been able to get it working correctly.

Below is my code:

```
initScene:
    scene.camera().position.z = 90;
    scene.camera().target = raketeOBJ.position();

onTouchEvent:
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
     if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        xpos = me.getX();
        ypos = me.getY();
        return true;
    }

    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        xpos = -1;
        ypos = -1;
        touchTurn = 0;
        touchTurnUp = 0;
        return true;
    }

    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        float xd = me.getX() - xpos;
        float yd = me.getY() - ypos;

        xpos = me.getX();
        ypos = me.getY();

        touchTurn = xd / -200f;
        touchTurnUp = yd / -200f;
        return true;
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(15);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(me);
}

UpdateScene:

    if (touchTurn != 0) {
        scene.camera().position.rotateY(touchTurn);
        touchTurn = 0;
    }

    if (touchTurnUp != 0) {
        scene.camera().position.rotateX(touchTurnUp);
        touchTurnUp = 0;
    }

Number3d target = scene.camera.target;
Number3d cp = scene.camera.position.clone();
// move position like target is (0,0,0)
cp.x -= target.x;
cp.y -= target.y;
cp.z -= target.z;

cp.roateX(angle);

// restore offset
cp.x += target.x;
cp.y += target.y;
cp.z += target.z;
scene.camera.position.setAllFrom(cp);
```

Comment: This Stack Exchange is for specific questions. This question is too broad. Please show us what you have attempted and what problems you are having. Then the people here can assist you. Thanks

Comment: I tried to implement a rotation of the camera around the sphere. The problem is that the rotation around axis X is not working properly. I used this code: http://pastebin.com/g9pLa61M  I think that method setLookAt() not working properly.

Comment: When I rotate the sphere vertically, I can't fully see it. For exampe, turning the planet Earth, I can not fully see the Antarctic, because the algorithm resets the camera down. Please tell me, is it possible to realize the camera rotation around an object without using the method "setLookAt"?

Answer (score 6):

A bit late but in case anyone has trouble with that, like me.

Rajawali offers a camera called [ArcballCamera](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/blob/master/rajawali/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/cameras/ArcballCamera.java), which does exactly what you/we are trying to do.

In your Renderer add the following:

```
 ArcballCamera arcball = new ArcballCamera(mContext, ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.contentView)); 
 arcball.setTarget(mObjectGroup); //your 3D Object

 arcball.setPosition(0,0,4); //optional

 getCurrentScene().replaceAndSwitchCamera(getCurrentCamera(), arcball);
```

now you can rotate and zoom the object without a dozen lines of code.

Comment: how can we set position of ArcballCamera respective to 3D object. Currently I have to change camera position as size of 3D object changes.

Answer (score 0):

setLookAt() needs to be called onDrawFrame if you want the camera to update regularly. But you  need to care more about creating a "RotateAroundAnimation". See here for more info: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2012/03/26/rajawali-tutorial-12-animation-classes/

You'll have to make yourAnimation.setTransformable3D(mCamera), and then it should control your main camera. I often use this methodology and then call the "yourAnimation.start()" on touch, or other external stimulus.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to rotate 3d model according as x and y

in Render class

```
public boolean left, right;
public boolean up, down;
```

and in onDrawFrame

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    super.onDrawFrame(glUnused);
    // getCurrentCamera().setRotY(getCurrentCamera().getRotY() + 1);
    if (left) {
        getCurrentCamera().setRotX(getCurrentCamera().getRotX() - 1);
    }
    if (right) {
        getCurrentCamera().setRotX(getCurrentCamera().getRotX() + 1);
    }
    if (up) {
        getCurrentCamera().setRotY(getCurrentCamera().getRotY() - 1);
    }
    if (down) {
        getCurrentCamera().setRotY(getCurrentCamera().getRotY() + 1);
    }
}
```

and in MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        xpos = event.getX();
        ypos = event.getY();
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        xpos = -1;
        ypos = -1;
        mRender.left = false;
        mRender.right = false;
        mRender.up = false;
        mRender.down = false;

    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        xd = event.getX() - xpos;
        yd = event.getY() - ypos;

        xpos = event.getX();
        ypos = event.getY();

        if (xd < 0) {
            mRender.up = true;
        } else {
            mRender.down = true;
        }
        if (yd < 0) {
            mRender.left = true;
        } else {
            mRender.right = true;
        }

    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

by this way, i can rotate my model :)